# Bold every odd li red in Recent Post Widget

Tags: wordpress

Is there away to bold every odd li in the Recent Post widget red? I have tried what usually would work:

```
:nth-child
```

but I can't seem to get it to work in wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this instead:

```
.widget_recent_entries li:nth-of-type(odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is close, it's just missing a bit on the end

```
li:nth-child(odd) {background: #F00; }
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but it just doesn't seem to work :( I can get it to color all of the li for the ".widget_recent_entries li" class but not odd or even.